# Consumer with varargs

Tags: java, functional-programming, variadic-functions, functional-interface

Suggest the following:

```
  Consumer<Object[]> consumer = (args) -> { /* Do something */ }
```

To make use of the consumer, I have to create an Object array. So, I'd have to write
something like

```
  consumer.accept(new Object[]{ object0, object1, ... });
```

Obviously, I'd rather have something like

```
  Consumer<Object...> consumer = (args) -> { /* Do something */ }
  consumer.accept(object0, object1, ...);
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: No. [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) (aka variadic function arguments) are not a **type**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Variable arity parameter* (*varargs*) is a syntactic element, a special token indicating that a method (*or a constructor*) expects `0` or more arguments of that type. And these arguments will be wrapped by an array (*so that technically they will constitute a single argument*) when the method gets executed.

Its usage is limited: a method can have only one parameter of variable arity and it must be defined in the last position.

Variable arity parameter isn't a type by itself. If you'll try to use *eclipses* `...` anywhere apart from the last position of a method (constructor) declaration, you'll get a compile error ([*take a look at JLS for more information*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)).

In order to use a variable number of arguments in a function, you can define a **functional interface** with a method of variable arity. And this method is the only place where elipses `...` needs to be used.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyConsumer<T> {
    void accept(T... items);
}
```

```
MyConsumer<String> myConsumer = items -> Stream.of(items).forEach(System.out::println);

myConsumer.accept("A", "B", "C");
```

*Will give an output:*

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 2):

But you can create your own functional interface as follows:

```
interface IntVarArgsConsumer {
        void accept(int ...s);
}
    
IntVarArgsConsumer printArray = arr-> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        
printArray.accept(1,2,3,4,5);
printArray.accept(1,2,3);
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3]
```

But I caution you **not** to mix `generic type parameters` and `varargs`.  Otherwise you can pollute the heap and get `ClassCastExceptions`. If you just want to process `Strings`, then use the `String` type.  If `Objects`, use the `Object` type.  But not some type `R` as you might see in other methods.